# Making a transparent white coverage between an image and a the content of a web page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a background for `OP.gif` which has as color transparent white that covers all of the web page and which makes the below input[type='text'] under that coverage (transparent white color). Thus the end-user cannot click on the input.

```
<input type="text" />
<span style="position:fixed;left:40%;top:40%;"><img src="OP.gif" />Welcome</span>
```

How do I to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input type="text" />
<div class="white-win">
   <span class="welcome"><img src="OP.gif" />Welcome</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.white-win {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
z-index: 99;
}
.welcome {position:absolute;left:40%;top:40%;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using an absolutely positioned overlay and an `rgba` background

something like this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tilwinjoy/Dt9Lc/)? The image should have an `z-index` greater than the overlay.